Solving mixed effects model by hand
coming from this discussion, in layman terms why one should use optimisation algorithms to estimate the parameters of a multilevel model?
Why a simple model such as y ~ x1 + (1|x2), where x2 has only two levels, cannot be solved by pencil and paper (theoretically)?
